# $\int_a^bf'=f(b)-f(a)$ if $f'$ is integrable, but not continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, derivatives, lebesgue-integral

Let $a<b$ and $f:(a,b)\to\mathbb R$ be differentiable (i.e. $f'$ exists, but is NOT necessarily continuous). Assuming that $f'$ is **Lebesgue integrable**, does it still hold that $$\int_a^bf'=f(b)-f(a)?\tag1$$ The claim is clearly true when $f'$ is continuous, since then $(1)$ is simply the second fundamental theorem of calculus. I wasn't able to come up with a couterexample, but I didn't found a reference of the claim either.

Comment: See [Cantor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function).

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net The Cantor function isn't differentiable, though. At least not everywhere.

Comment: What you claim holds true if you slightly strengthen your conditions: it's sufficient for $f'$ to be Riemann integrable. Wikipedia also claims that it's true if the derivative is Lebesgue integrable, but shows no proof or reference, and I can't come up with a proof. The weaker version with Riemann integrals is shown with a proof, though: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus

Comment: According to Rudin: Real and complex analysis, Theorem 7.21: If $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable everywhere and $f' \in L^1([a,b])$ then $f(x)-f(a)=\int_a^x f'(t) dt$ $(x \in [a,b])$.

Comment: There are examples where $f$ is differentiable everywhere, but $f'$ is neither Lebesgue integrable nor Riemann integrable.  Google "gauge integral" for more information.  The gauge integral ( = Kurzweil integral, Henstock integral, etc.) is an integral where your question has  $\int_a^b f' = f(b)-f(a)$ .

Comment: Just to confuse the issue.  You cannot replace "$f'$ is Lebesgue integrable" with "$f'$ is continuous on $(a,b)$".   It is true, however, that if $f'$ is continuous on $(a,b)$ and also *bounded* then it must be Lebesgue integrable.  In general, not otherwise.

Answer (score 9):

There are a few versions of the FTC, which depend on the hypotheses you decide to impose. All of these can be found in Rudin's RCA chapter $7$. For the version you're asking about, note that Rudin's theorem $7.21$ is the following (apparently this version of the theorem isn't as well-known as the other one involving the equivalence with AC functions):

> If $f:[\alpha,\beta]\to\Bbb{R}$ is differentiable *at every point* of $[\alpha,\beta]$ and $f'$ is Lebesgue integrable on $[\alpha,\beta]$, then for all $x\in [\alpha,\beta]$, we have
> \begin{align}
> f(x)-f(\alpha)&=\int_{\alpha}^xf'(t)\,dt
> \end{align}

Note that one can very easily extend this to functions with values in $\Bbb{C}$, or really any finite-dimensional real/complex vector space (and if you manage to define integrals for arbitrary Banach-space valued mappings, you can deduce this theorem for those maps as well by using Hahn-Banach, and reducing to the scalar-valued case above).

Note also that the hypothesis here is that the function is differentiable at every point of the interval; this is definitely not the weakest possible assumption, though based on the way you phrased your question, I presume this is what you're interested in. However, some restrictions are necessary: if you only assume the function is differentiable at almost every point of the interval, with the a.e defined function $f'$ being Lebesgue integrable, then the statement is false, as mentioned in the comments; the Cantor function provides a counter example.

In your case, you're asking about open intervals, and the answer is still yes, because we can just apply the above theorem to every compact subset of $(a,b)$. More precisely,

> If $f:(a,b)\to\Bbb{C}$ is differentiable at every point of $(a,b)$, and $f'$ is Lebesgue integrable on $(a,b)$, then $f$ extends to a continuous function $F$ on $[a,b]$, and for all $x\in [a,b]$, we have
> \begin{align}
> F(x)-F(a)&=\int_a^xf'(t)\,dt.
> \end{align}

$f$ has a continuous extension because if you fix an $x_0\in (a,b)$, then $f'\in L^1((a,b))$ implies that the mapping $x\mapsto \int_{x_0}^xf'(t)\,dt$ is uniformly continuous (it's actually absolutely continuous) on $(a,b)$, hence has a continuous extension to the closure $[a,b]$.

Comment: Interesting fact about the case where $f$ is differentiable only almost everywhere : indeed the statement is not true and Cantor function is a counterexample, but one can notice that the inequality $$\int_a^b f'(t) dt \leq f(b)-f(a)$$ is always true.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe surely that inequality requires some additional hypotheses. If it was true for all functions $f$ which are a.e differentiable with $f'\in L^1$, then $-f$ satisfies these conditions as well, so the inequality would hold for $-f$ as well, and thus we have equality (which obviously isn't right).

Comment: My bad. You are obviously right. If $f$ is continuous and increasing, then the inequality holds.

Comment: @peek-a-boo  You say "differentiable *at every single point* of the interval is crucial."  You *can* allow a countable   exceptional set.  As you say, however, you cannot in general allow an uncountable set even if it has measure zero.

Comment: @B.S.Thomson fair enough; I guess my language wasn't precise enough. My goal was to emphasize the distinction in hypotheses a.e differentiable vs everywhere differentiable, and how that seemingly innocuous weakening of the hypothesis affects things. My goal wasn't maximal generality (lol because I'm not knowledgeable enough): though based on the way I have stated things, it's clear how to generalize the theorem atleast for $f:(a,b)\to\Bbb{R}$ continuous everywhere, differentiable with finitely many exceptions (of course continuity can be dropped if we take jump discontinuities into account).

Answer (score 0):

As stated at the moment there is nothing indicating that $f$ is continuous at the endpoints, *so the statement is false*.   But an easy edit changes it to this:

**Theorem.**    Suppose that   $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb R$ is continuous and differentiable on  $(a,b)$ excepting an at most countable number of points.   If $f'$ is  Lebesgue integrable then
$$ \int_a^b f'(x)\,dx = f(b)-f(a). \tag{*}$$

I think there is a particularly simple way of thinking about this. But it comes with a warning:  *you have to know integration theory one more step past the Lebesgue theory.*  As Gerry Edgar pointed out in a comment, many of us exposed to that theory immediately think of the problem in this context.  Under these hypotheses we know that (*) holds in the sense of the Denjoy-Perron-Henstock-Kurzweil integral, but can fail for the Lebesgue integral.  That integral includes the Lebesgue integral so the extra hypothesis that $f'$ is Lebesgue integrable is both necessary and sufficient.

---

---

Here is another way of looking at this, but also invokes some material past the usual Lebesgue theory, namely a well-known generalization of absolute continuity.

1. If  $g$ is Lebesgue integrable on  $[a,b]$  then there is an absolutely continuous function  $G:[a,b]\to \mathbb R$  so that $G'=g$ almost everywhere and
   $$ \int_a^b g(t)\,dt = G(b)-G(a).$$

> [Well known]

2. On the other hand if $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb R$ is continuous and $f'$ exists at all but countably many points then  $f$ is  ACG${}_*$.

> [Well known in the 1930s and known now only to students of
> nonabsolutely convergent integrals such as the
> Denjoy-Perron-Henstock-Kurzweil integral.]

Now put these together assuming $g=f'$.

Thus  $f -G$ satisfies  $(f-G)'=0$ a.e.  and  $f-G$ is ACG${}_*$ simply because $G$  is absolutely continuous and $f$ is ACG${}_*$ .

Every such function is constant.  So  $f(b)-f(a)=G(b)-G(a)$.

$$ \int_a^b f'(t)\,dt =  \int_a^b g(t)\,dt = G(b)-G(a) = f(b)-f(a).$$