Can I say $u^{'}(x)=0$ everywhere if $\int_0^1|u^{'}(x)|=0$？
Can I say $u^{'}(x)=0$ everywhere if $\int_0^1|u^{'}(x)|=0$, $u \in C[0,1]$ , $u(0)=u(1)=0$

Background is in Dirichlet problem for unique solution, where $u \in C^2[0,1]$,
suppose two solution exists, $u=u_1-u_2$, and $\implies$ $\int_0^1|u^{'}(x)|=0$
$\implies$ $u^{'}(x)=0$ everywhere ($u^{'}(x)$ is continuous)

I wonder if we have weaken condition, if $\int_0^1|u^{'}(x)|=0$, $u \in C[0,1]$ , $u(0)=u(1)$ , can we still say $u^{'}(x)=0$ everywhere?
I can only $\int_0^1|u^{'}(x)|=0$ $\implies$ $u^{'}(x)=0$ almost everywhere, but can I say $u^{'}(x)=0$ everywhere?
I searched and found out Cantor function, so I can construct a Cantor function that increases and then a reverse Cantor function that decreases so that $u(1)=u(0)$ again. But I think Cantor function's derivative doesn't exist on measure 0, but $\int_0^1|u^{'}(x)|=0$ at least implies $u^{'}(x)$  is defined everywhere which means $u^{'}(x)$ exist on [0,1]. So can I say $u^{'}(x)=0$ everywhere?
Edit according to comment: the background material I read only says $\int_0^1|u^{'}(x)|=0$,but I think I can add $u$ is differentiable at every point. Then why the answer is yes?

Recall Darboux's Theorem: The derivative has the intermediate value property even if it need not be continuous.

If $u \in C[0,1]$,  $u'$ need not even exist. State your assumptions clearly. If $u$ is differentiable at every point then the answer to your question is YES.

@Ted Shifrin why does Darboux's Theorem implies the answer is yes?

@geetha290krm why the answer is yes?

Rudin's RCA proves that if $u$ is differentiable at every point and $u'$ is integrable then $u$ is actually absolutely continuous.

See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4343603/int-abf-fb-fa-if-f-is-integrable-but-not-continuous/4343639#4343639

A formatting tip: u^{'} looks really weird. Derivatives are meant to be written simply as u'.
